# SQL find Max of count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, max

I'm trying to get the unitcode from this

```
SELECT
    max(maxcount) 
FROM(
        SELECT
            COUNT(studid) maxcount,
            semester,
            e.unitcode,
            u.unitname,
            to_char(ofyear, 'yyyy')
        FROM
            uni.enrolment e Join uni.unit u 
        ON 
            e.unitcode = u.unitcode
        WHERE
            to_char(ofyear, 'yyyy') = '2013'
        GROUP BY
            semester,
            e.unitcode,
            u.unitname,
            to_char(ofyear, 'yyyy')
    );
```

But I'm unable to retrieve it. 
I'm looking for the max value corresponding to the unit code.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, your code is not valid MySQL, so either the code is wrong or the tag is wrong.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?  What do you mean by `unable to retrieve it`?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I want only the record with max count and corresponding unit code to be retrieved. My query gives only the max count. I'm unsure about how to fetch the unitcode

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max per unit code, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT unitcode, MAX(maxcount) 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(studid) as maxcount, semester, e.unitcode, u.unitname
      FROM uni.enrolment e JOIN
           uni.unit u 
           ON  e.unitcode = u.unitcode
      WHERE ofyear >= DATE '2013-01-01' AND ofyear < DATE '2014-01-01'
      GROUP BY semester, e.unitcode, u.unitname
     ) eu
GROUP BY unitcode;
```

Based on your comment, you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(studid) as maxcount, semester, e.unitcode, u.unitname
FROM uni.enrolment e JOIN
     uni.unit u 
     ON e.unitcode = u.unitcode
WHERE ofyear >= DATE '2013-01-01' AND ofyear < DATE '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY semester, e.unitcode, u.unitname
ORDER BY maxcount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve only the unitcode which has the max count. The above query retrieves all the records for the unitcode.